# Python-Zeroconf を使ったデータ送信方法は存在しますか？

Tags: python, network

[Python-Zeroconf](https://pypi.org/project/zeroconf/) のドキュメントを見ました。

このドキュメントでは、Python-Zeroconf のリスナー(受信側?)を作成する方法が以下のように示されています。

```
from zeroconf import ServiceBrowser, Zeroconf

class MyListener:

    def remove_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        print("Service %s removed" % (name,))

    def add_service(self, zeroconf, type, name):
        info = zeroconf.get_service_info(type, name)
        print("Service %s added, service info: %s" % (name, info))
    
zeroconf = Zeroconf()
listener = MyListener()
browser = ServiceBrowser(zeroconf, "_http._tcp.local.", listener)
try:
    input("Press enter to exit...\n\n")
finally:
    zeroconf.close()
```

しかし、データを送信する方法を書いていないように見えます。
Python-Zeroconf を使用してデータを送信することは可能ですか？
出来る場合、どのようにすれば送信できますか？

Comment: 回答へのコメントを見ると[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701/26370)のように見えます。質問の記述だとフリーフォーマットデータの通信を希望しているように取れますが、[Zeroconf - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf)も[Bonjour - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour)も回答に示されたようにデバイスやサービスを検索して使えるようにするもののようなので、目的と質問がイマイチ合っていない(内容が理解されていない？)感じですね。元々の目的は何かを明確にして別途質問した方が良さそうです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[zeroconf 0.28.1](https://pypi.org/project/zeroconf/) のページには、

```
Pure Python Multicast DNS Service Discovery Library (Bonjour/Avahi compatible)
```

[直訳] Pythonだけで書かれたマルチキャストでDNSサービスを発見するライブラリ
と書かれています。
『データを送信する』という機能を提供しているとは思えません。

zeroconfがデータを送信するものだというのは、どこで得た情報なのでしょうか？
"zeroconfでデータを送信する"というような事が書いてあるページのURL等を質問に追加してください。

---

以下のページには zeroconf を使ってGoogle Homeを探して、それに喋らせているプログラムが書かれています。

[Python 3 から Google Home に喋らせる（低遅延） - Qiita](https://qiita.com/rukihena/items/8af9b8baed49542c033d)

zeroconfは、IPマルチキャスト(同じネットワークに接続されている複数の機器に、データを同時送信する方法)を使って、DNSやGoogle Homeなどの機器から応答を収集し、必要とする機器を特定するものなのではないでしょうか？

Comment: たぶん質問の参照先のページに、テレビ録画やビデオストリーミング配信関連のプロジェクトで使用されていると書かれているようだからでは？ 他には関連は無いけど互換性はあるというBonjourのこんな記事 [Python で通信 : Bonjour を試す](https://ameblo.jp/oyasai10/entry-10611645943.html) もあるので何かしらの通信は出来るのかもしれません。

Comment: Pythonを使ってBonjourを使用する方法を探しており、送信方法がないか探している形です。PythonでBonjourを使える方法がこのライブラリしか見つからないため、このライブラリで送信する方法がもしかしたらあるのではないかと思い質問に至りました。